# Missing Option to Publish Map as a Map Image Layer

Tags: arcgis-pro

I am trying to publish my map as a map image layer on ArcGIS Pro, but for some reason, the option is not available under Layer Type options in the "Share As a Web Layer" tool. Does anyone know what I need to do to make the option appear? I think it may be a conditional statement issue where I need to click something to make the option appear. I have the Advanced License in ArcGIS Pro and the Publisher role on Online ArcGIS Pro. I should be able to have the ability to publish my map as a online map image layer, but for some reason, I don't see that option available.

Answer (score 2):

This will depend on whether you are sharing your web layer to ArcGIS Online (AGOL) or ArcGIS for Enterprise (Portal).

[Types of web layers](https://enterprise.arcgis.com/en/portal/latest/use/layers.htm#:%7E:text=The%20following%20are%20the%20types%20of%20web%20layers%20you%20can%20publish%20to%20or%20add%20to%20an%20ArcGIS%20portal%20as%20an%20item%3A) in documentation describes that a map image layer is available for ArcGIS Enterprise.

The ArcGIS Online documentation [Types of Web Layers AGOL](https://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/manage-data/hosted-web-layers.htm#:%7E:text=publish%20hosted%20layers-,Types%20of%20hosted%20layers,-You%20can%20publish) describes that the only types of layers you can share are Feature, Tile or Vector Tile.

In short, ArcGIS Online doesn't host map image layers currently so this could be the reason.